# Не могу выбрать фреймворк для сервера

Tags: android, сервер, веб-сервер, клиент-сервер, backend

Хочу написать сервер который будет получать данные от android приложения обрабатывать их и отправлять на микроконтроллер и соответственно наоборот. Проблема в том что я не очень хорошо разбираюсь в back end и не могу выбрать не тип сервера не фреймворк на котором он будет работать по этому хотел бы попросить помощь у вас буду очень благодарен.
И ещё одно маленькое уточнение.
Правильно ли я понимаю что web сервер для этих целей не подходит?

Comment: Смотря как вы видите взаимодействие, должен ли сервер инициировать какие-то действия или всё будет инициировать только клиент. Если только клиент будет активничать, то достаточно веб-сервиса на элементарном `Flask`, например. Хотя вы язык не указали, в зависимости от языка будет свой фреймворк для бэкэнда.

Comment: Взаимодействие с сервером должно происходить следующим образом. Андроид клиент регистрируется в системе и получает свой айди, у каждого wifi девайса тоже есть свое айди. Клиент отправляет запрос на сервер в котором указаны айди клиента и девайса. Сервер обрабатывает этот запрос и отправляет на девайс, с девайса получает ответ и отправляет обратно клиенту. Я думаю что на сервере должен быть DB с клиентами и девайсами но могу ошибаться. Насчёт языка могу сказать что python мне вполне подходит. А пиковый онлайн сервера не будет превышать 100-200 человек. На данный момент вроде бы все.

Comment: Возможно подойдет - ktor

Comment: Вы забыли уточнить как сервер будет взаимодействовать с микроконтроллером?